# How to Make a Thematic Map with ORACLE using MapXtreme?

Tags: mapinfo, oracle-dbms, thematic-map

I want to make a thematic map with Oracle source longitude and latitude values.
I  have made thematic maps with tab file source.  Part of the code looks like this:

```
MapInfo.Engine.Session.Current.MapFactory[0].Layers.Insert(0, new MapInfo.Mapping.FeatureLayer(MapInfo.Engine.Session.Current.Catalog.GetTable("SPA_POINTS"), "TempThematicLayer", "TempThematicLayer")); 
 MapInfo.Mapping.FeatureLayer lyr = harita.Layers["TempThematicLayer"] as MapInfo.Mapping.FeatureLayer;

    MapInfo.Mapping.Thematics.RangedTheme ranthm = new MapInfo.Mapping.Thematics.RangedTheme(lyr, "MAGNITUDE", "SPA_POINTSThematic", 10, MapInfo.Mapping.Thematics.DistributionMethod.EqualCountPerRange);
```

What can I use  instead of:

```
GetTable("SPA_POINTS")
```

or how can I make a thematic map with an Oracle table?

Comment: is your source data in tab/oracle in lat/lng? Do you know how to load the tab file into oracle with the correct metadata?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have accessed Oracle table,it's opened as Server Table as an instance of MapInfo.Data.Table which means you can apply thematic option as you do on native tables(no difference in code).

```
MapInfo.Data.Table table = MapInfo.Engine.Session.Current.Catalog.GetTable("SPA_POINTS");
MapInfo.Mapping.FeatureLayer lyr = new MapInfo.Mapping.FeatureLayer(table, "TempThematicLayer", "TempThematicLayer");
MapInfo.Engine.Session.Current.MapFactory[0].Layers.Insert(0, lyr);
MapInfo.Mapping.Thematics.RangedTheme ranthm = new MapInfo.Mapping.Thematics.RangedTheme(lyr, "MAGNITUDE", "SPA_POINTSThematic", 10, MapInfo.Mapping.Thematics.DistributionMethod.EqualCountPerRange);
```

After this do not forget to refresh map
Best Regards